# How to load local html file in alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm currently making a web application and need to load a local index.html file as the url, but i'm kinda lost. I'm familiar with the loadHTMLString from WebKit, but kinda lost when using alamofire.

I've tried to loadHTMLString in WebKit with webView with great

```
func registerShift() {
   let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")!

   let parameters = [
      "brugernavn": "user@email.dk",
      "password": "testPass"
   ] 

   Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseString { response in
      switch response.result {
      case .success:
        if let value = response.result.value {
           print(value)
        }
      case .failure(let error):
           print(error)
      }
   }
}
```

I expected the website to actually submit the form, however instead it printes the HTML of the local index.html. The local index.html file is just a simple form containing input (name = brugernavn) and input (name = password).

Comment: the url must be url of a restApi call, not an html file.

Comment: An HTML file is actually just plain text, a document. For the same reason you cannot run Swift files without compiling them in Xcode you cannot run HTML files without an appropriate processing engine like WebKit.